# target list item in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I have a list and I'm checking if the list item has two specific classes. If it does, I want to change the background of that list item to blue. however my code doesn't seem to work. How can I target that specific list item? The alert works fine, it's just the colour which doesn't.

```
if (($("#all-colls-list li:contains(" + itemName + ")").hasClass("groupAdded")) && ($("#all-colls-list li:contains(" + itemName + ")").hasClass("selAdded")) ) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
                alert("has both classes");
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [class selectors](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) instead of [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) will allow you to achieve what you're looking for with a single selector, and to obtain references to the elements you want to modify:

```
$("#all-colls-list li:contains(" + itemName + ").groupAdded.selAdded")
    .css("background-color", "blue");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#all-colls-list li:contains(" + itemName + ")").each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("groupAdded") && $(this).hasClass("selAdded")) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

that `$(this)` is probably undefined since your accessing that element directly in the if above. Calling all the selector again in the .`css` function should solve your problem

```
if (($("#all-colls-list li:contains(" + itemName + ")").hasClass("groupAdded")) && ($("#all-colls-list li:contains(" + itemName + ")").hasClass("selAdded")) ) {
                    $("#all-colls-list li:contains(" + itemName + ")").css("background-color", "blue");
                    alert("has both classes");
                }
```